# Are Mr.5 and Miss Valentine still alive?

Tags: one-piece

While I'm yet to reach the current parts of the story, a friend told meg that in the Dressrosa Arc, two characters appeared, using the Bomb-Bomb and the Ton-Ton Fruit, the same used by the two former Baroque Works members named in the title.

However, the Wiki has no mention of these cases, making me assume that canonically, either they are not dead or said DF abilities don't appear.

What is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Ton-Ton no mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Ton_Ton_no_Mi) was eaten by [Machivise](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Machvise).
The [Pamu-Pamu no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Pamu_Pamu_no_Mi) was eaten by [Gladius](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gladius).

The two fruits eaten by Miss Valentine and Mr. 5 are the [Kilo-Kilo no mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kilo_Kilo_no_Mi) and [Bomu-Bomu no mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bomu_Bomu_no_Mi) respectively.

The Kilo-Kilo no mi and the Ton-Ton no mi are both similar but they have differences:

- The Kilo-Kilo no mi allows a user to change their weight from 1 - 10,000 kg. This means the user can *decrease* their weight below normal as well as increase it up to 10,000 kg.
- The Ton-Ton no mi allows a user to *increase* their weight by presumably any amount

The Bomu-Bomu no mi and the Pamu-Pamu no mi are also indeed similar but have differences, which are noted on the Wikia page for Pamu-Pamu no mi:

> This ability is very similar to the Bomu Bomu no Mi, as they both involve explosions. The main difference is that while Mr. 5 is able to turn himself or any part of him into a bomb, Gladius can cause himself or inorganic objects to swell up and rupture explosively.

Both Miss Valentine and Mr. 5 are believed to be alive at this time.

Comment: So it was a major misunderstaning, thank you!

Comment: @Katamori Not a problem :>

Comment: If you read the manga you should at least know that they were alive up till past enies lobby, thanks to the shorts on the title page of every chapter